# Boot Issues on Ubuntu 18.04 (Asus Vivobook S14)

Tags: boot, 18.04, asus

I have been having issues when booting and rebooting on my laptop (Asus Vivobook S14, i7 processor, GeForce MX150 graphics card). I have a dual-boot setup with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. Oftentimes when I reboot, it doesn't get to the login screen, though it does get past Grub. At this point, I have to physically power off the laptop and try again, and it seems to boot to login roughly 1/3 of the time. Once I get to the login screen, there are no issues.

'sudo reboot' always triggers this issue, as does restarting from the menu in the top right. Also, if I try to go to recovery mode, it can get stuck at 'Loading initial ramdisk...' at which point I have to physically restart the computer. I've also been trying to get scripts to run on startup and have tried cron, adding to ./xsessionrc, and adding to Startup Applications, and none of these work, and I'm not sure if the problems are related.

I've been having these issues since I installed Ubuntu a few months ago, and hoped it would go away through updates. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: New problem: If I sleep my laptop, it seems to reboot it, since things like 'touch and drag' become re-enabled (I disable it on reboot).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues.

I install (or update) a new kernel whit ukuu.

After that, the system work fine except because show an error at boot time related at acpi.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. Can you tell me your system specs and what Linux kernel you used?

Comment: I have a asus S430FN (S14 whit core i5 + nvidia mx150). I update to the last kernel available in ukuu.

Comment: I also tried updating to the latest kernel, but unfortunately it didn't seem to work for me. However, the newer updates seem to be slowly fixing the problem. I will wait for a bit longer to see if the newer kernels installed through Software Updater as opposed to UKUU will somehow solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen ever since I got my Obsidian N85_87hp6 laptop with i7 CPU and 1060gtx GPU. It has a switching technology (Optimus) that switches from dedicated GPU to integrated that doesn't work well in Linux.

Unfortunately there is nothing that can be done as the nvidia-driver is proprietary.

I've found that it especially doesn't boot to the login screen if I have my monitors attached.

Nonetheless, what you can try is to press `Alt + F2` at the dark screen, login with your user at the prompt and enter `startx` to start the UI session. If it doesn't work, the output of the command will show you the location of the log files. Hope it helps.